# C++ for loop/char pointer "hack"

Tags: c++

I have a small piece of code which does something funny, but I can't figure out how it does it.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char text[] = "object";
    for(char *ptr = &text[0]; *ptr != '\0'; ptr+=2) 
    {   
        cout << ptr << endl;
        ptr--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What's happening is that it goes from [1], [2], [3] and so on, to the end of the string every time, printing the content out. I cant understand how it does that, as pointer never gets dereferenced, but right letters seems to get printed. I would assume that instead of the letters of the string, the pointer values would print as weird characters thats all, yet, that's not what happens.

Comment: This is far from a hack. I think any C++ book explains the cause.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes isn't it undefined behavior?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore why would it?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes after the first iteration, `ptr` points 1 before the start of the array. And then you do pointer arithmetics on it.

Comment: But isn't `ptr--; ptr++;` guaranteed to be back at the same value, even if it goes out of range for a bit?

Comment: @MrLister it probably will on 99% of compilers.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Your comment frightens me.

Comment: @MrLister no it's not guaranteed, it's UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **undefined behavior**. The first iteration, `ptr` points to `"object"`. All good, prints that out, but then you do `ptr--`. So now, `ptr` points to memory you no longer own. As long as you don't dereference it or do pointer arithmetics on it, it's ok. But you do when you increment it in the loop - `ptr+=2`.

#### Why it's behaving like this:

At the first iteration, `ptr` points to `"object"`, so it prints that. `cout::operator << (const char*)` prints a null-terminated string. No `char` needs dereferencing.

On the second iteration, `ptr` is decremented and then increased by `2`, pointing to `"bject"`. And so on...

Comment: I never knew doing arithmetic on it was UB, only dereferencing. I guess  you learn something new every day :p

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, I was messing with the code, changed &text[0] and forgot to set it back to 1.

Comment: @chris because usually you only operate within the bounds of an array you already own.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, true, I just never thought it'd be bad to go out and back in.

Comment: @chris hang out on SO enough and you'll learn pretty damn quickly.

Comment: So where is the UB part here?

Comment: @lezebulon the first paragraph explains just that.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, normally the address would be printed. Except there's a special overload for `char *`, which considers it as a C string and outputs all the characters, starting at `ptr`, up until it finds a zero (`\0`).

... or that would be what happens if your code was correct, because as it is now, it invokes UB by decrementing `ptr` on the first iteration (`ptr` moves out of range) and then incrementing it by 2 right after.

---

If you want to display the *address* of the pointer, cast it to `void *`:

```
cout << static_cast<void *>(ptr) << endl;
```

Comment: what if I just cast i to (int)?

Comment: I assume that by `i` you mean `ptr`. If that's the case, then you'll display an integer.

Comment: @user1125518 But why would you want to do that? With any luck, your pointer isn't even the same size as an int.

Comment: Because the program is running into UB. (I usually comment on downvotes when the reason isn't clear, but I thought it was in this case - at least if you had read the other answers).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I still think a downvote for that is somewhat harsh.

Comment: I will be happy to remove it after you edit the answer. But as it is, it's wrong, as it misses the most important issue in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing really hacky here. There's an `ostream::operator<<(const char *p)` which prints a character string. The pointer is walked along the string and the program prints it starting from various positions. The only weird thing is the crazy +2, -1 pointer incrementing.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/ for some more information about operator<<.